# androidx.paging.InitialDataSource cannot be cast to com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestoreDataSource

Tags: android, firebase

Here is what I get on `mAdapter.startListening()`
I have extended my adapter from `FirestorePagingAdapter`

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.valorem.flobooks.debug, PID: 14886
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.paging.InitialDataSource cannot be cast to com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestoreDataSource
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter$5.apply(FirestorePagingAdapter.java:98)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter$5.apply(FirestorePagingAdapter.java:95)
        at androidx.lifecycle.Transformations$2.onChanged(Transformations.java:143)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.onChanged(MediatorLiveData.java:152)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.considerNotify(LiveData.java:133)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.dispatchingValue(LiveData.java:146)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:468)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:234)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData$Source.plug(MediatorLiveData.java:141)
        at androidx.lifecycle.MediatorLiveData.onActive(MediatorLiveData.java:118)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.changeActiveCounter(LiveData.java:390)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData$ObserverWrapper.activeStateChanged(LiveData.java:466)
        at androidx.lifecycle.LiveData.observeForever(LiveData.java:234)
        at com.firebase.ui.firestore.paging.FirestorePagingAdapter.startListening(FirestorePagingAdapter.java:181)
        at com.valorem.flobooks.helpAndSupport.CategoryQuestionsFragment.onStart(CategoryQuestionsFragment.kt:91)
```

[image]

Comment: Have you found a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I fixed this issue by updating my grade file.

Initially I only had:

```
dependencies {
implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.2")
}
```

but then I added the rest shown in the documentation here

https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/paging

```
dependencies {
 implementation("androidx.paging:paging-runtime:2.1.2") 

    // alternatively - without Android dependencies for testing
    testImplementation("androidx.paging:paging-common:2.1.2") 

    // optional - RxJava support
    implementation("androidx.paging:paging-rxjava2:2.1.2")

}
```